# Auto Mapper Error - "No Parameterless constructor defined for this object"

Tags: c#, .net-core, mapping, automapper

Ultimately, I am trying to map from VehicleViewMOdel -> Vehicle. Source listed below. Of note is the fact that two properties from each class are of different types.

code that does the mapping

```
var newVehicle = Mapper.Map<Vehicle>(vehicleData_);
```

code for classes being mapped
    public class VehicleViewModel
    {
        public VehicleViewModel()
        {

```
    }
    //Fuel Economy is in L/Km
    public float CityFuelEconomy {get;set;}
    public float HighwayFuelEconomy {get;set;}
    public float ListPrice {get;set;}
    public float SoldPrice{get;set;}
    [Required]
    public int ModelForeignKey {get;set;}
    [Required]
    public int DealerForeignKey{get;set;}
    public string Notes{get; set;}
    public string Color{get; set;}
}



public class Vehicle
{
    public Vehicle()
    {

    }
    [Key]
    public int Id {get; set;}
    //Fuel Economy is in L/Km
    public float CityFuelEconomy {get;set;}
    public float HighwayFuelEconomy {get;set;}
    public float ListPrice {get;set;}
    public float SoldPrice{get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("VehicleModelId")]
    public virtual VehicleModels ModelForeignKey {get;set;}
    [ForeignKey("VehicleDealerId")]
    public virtual Dealer DealerForeignKey{get;set;}
    public string Notes{get; set;}
    public string Color{get; set;}
}
```

To handle mapping the properties with different types types, I used the following 'formember' in my automapper configuration (startup.cs)

```
Mapper.Initialize(config =>
        {
            config.CreateMap<VehicleViewModel, Vehicle>()
            .ForMember(dest => dest.DealerForeignKey, opt => opt.MapFrom<DealerResolver>())
            .ForMember(dest => dest.ModelForeignKey, opt => opt.MapFrom<VehicleModelResolver>()).ReverseMap();
        });
```

The resolvers mentioned (VehicleModelResolver and DealerResolver) simply take the source property (in this case of thype integer) and return an object of the correct type for the Vehicle.ModelForeignKey and Vehicle.DealerForeignKey

```
private IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepo;
    public DealerResolver(IVehicleRepository vehicleRepo_)
    {
        _vehicleRepo = vehicleRepo_;
    }

    public Dealer Resolve(VehicleViewModel source, Vehicle destination, Dealer destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<Dealer> dealers = _vehicleRepo.GetDealerById(source.DealerForeignKey).ToList();
        return dealers.FirstOrDefault();
    }


public class VehicleModelResolver : IValueResolver<VehicleViewModel, Vehicle, VehicleModels>
{
    private IVehicleRepository _vehicleRepo;
    public VehicleModelResolver(IVehicleRepository vehicleRepo_)
    {
        _vehicleRepo = vehicleRepo_;
    }

    public VehicleModels Resolve(VehicleViewModel source, Vehicle destination, VehicleModels destMember, ResolutionContext context)
    {
        List<VehicleModels> vehModels = _vehicleRepo.GetModelById(source.ModelForeignKey).ToList();
        return vehModels.FirstOrDefault();
    }
}
```

When the code is run I see the error message 'No Parameterless constructor defined for this object.'
Stepping through the code at runtime reveals the mapping is happening just fine for all properties, until VehicleViewModel.MOdelForeignKey.

There is something about mapping VehicleViewModel.ModelForeignKey -> Vehicle.ModelForeignKey that I just cannot see at the moment. Like I said before, I realise the properties are of different types, but then the resolvers should take care of this. Any Ideas?

**Update** - there has been a suggestion on this - The DI was configured incorrectly. Made a quick video detailing the problem and its resolution https://youtu.be/tGU7TjDvSK8

Comment: Most likely your [DI configuration](http://docs.automapper.org/en/latest/Dependency-injection.html) is broken.

Comment: Thanks for you input. This is a project I am doing in my free time, so may take me a while to respond.

Comment: honestly - I still dont have this working after at least 3 hours trying different things. The best I can say is that automapper does know 'know' how to construct one of the parameters to an  IValueResolver instance. Any chance of a hint or at least a code example with a simple explanation? the code itself is at https://github.com/Ted95153420/CarWebApp  (Branch is chapter6_API)

Comment: That's _exactly_ what the documentation does. I would start  with that, see how it works, and then build on it. There is even a dedicated section for .Net Core.

Comment: Yes - reading the documentation did solve my problem. I documented the problem and the resolution in slightly more detail in a screencast. https://youtu.be/tGU7TjDvSK8

Answer (score -1, accepted):

youtu.be/tGU7TjDvSK8

Not really my answer, I just made a video to make it super clear. - I'd like to credit Lucian Bargaoanu for the real answer.